# SQL Server Login failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have SQL 2008 Developer Edition on my Development Computer.

I was able to connect and work on the SQL Server Edition located in my Server.

I am not sure, since yesterday i am facing a log-in problem.

Error is as follows. Is there any way to fix this issue.

The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during connection initialization process before login. 
Possible causes include the following:  the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server; the server was too busy to accept new connections; or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) 
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

Comment: Was/Is the SQL server still running when you try to connect?

Comment: Yes it is still running. Noticed that Firewall is turned on. I turned it off, i am able to connect. I just want to make sure that this is because of Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to login as windows account then you can try below...
Go to Security-->login
if you find a red error downward facing on sa login then right click on sa --> properties --> go to status page --> login (make the radio button enabled).

I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Are you mentioning to do this in my Developer Computer or in the Server machine ?? Assuming to login from SQL

Comment: on developer computer, if you can able to login with windows authentication then you can try the above method.